# Compiling Wireshark packet dissector

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I want to build a Wireshark packet dissector of my own and followed the procedure given at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html .

However, I do not understand how to compile my dissector and place the dll in the plugins folder. I followed this guide https://www.sewio.net/open-sniffer/develop/how-to-compile-your-wireshark-dissector/ till step 2. But couldn't understand what to do at step 3.

I tried running nmake but it shows no such cmd command.
I am using the Wireshark installation for Windows.

How can I compile my dissector and run it? Also is it necessary to build Wireshark from Source code in order to run custom packet dissectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since you're working on the Windows platform, you should be sure to read and follow very carefully the official [Win32/64 Step-by-Step Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html) section of the Wireshark Developer's Guide.

Second, if you're building a plugin, you should be sure to carefully read the [README.plugins](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.plugins;hb=HEAD) file.

You **will** need to compile the Wireshark sources if you're building a dissector written as a C plugin or builtin, but you **won't** need to build the Wireshark sources if you write your dissector as a Lua plugin.  If you're interested in Lua, you might start at the [Wireshark Lua wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua).

There's also another less well-known method of building a dissector using [wsgd](http://wsgd.free.fr/).  I have no experience with wsgd, but for an introduction to all 3 methods, you may wish to review Graham Bloice's presentation from [Sharkfest '15](https://sharkfestus.wireshark.org/sf15) titled, ["Wireshark Dissectors - 3 ways to eat bytes"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwia6bfzo5TaAhVHMawKHRd3A7EQFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsharkfestus.wireshark.org%2Fassets%2Fpresentations15%2F03.pptx&usg=AOvVaw2tBDo-0gYx2VHRlfd8sL6B).

Comment: You should be able to compile plugins if the package `wireshark-devel` or `-dev` is installed only.

Answer (score 3):

**five steps** to make a c plugin (custom dissector) for wireshark:

**1.** compile the wireshark source code once

**2.** Create a source file in "wireshark\plugins\epan\foo" directory (for example named packet-foo.c )

**3.** Copy another plugin source file and configuration as templates and edit it

**4.** recompile the wireshark source code

**5.** start wireshark and test

for detail, you can check my post here [show you how to compile the c language plugin for wireshark 3.1 step by step (windows platform 2019-3-20)](https://blog.fjh1997.top/2019/03/29/show-you-how-to-compile-the-c-language-plugin-for-wireshark-3.1-step-by-step-(windows-platform-2019-3-20)/)

Comment: How can the dissector be compiled separately? "Compile the wireshark source code once" is a lot to ask, especially in a secure environment. Chocolatey Qt (huge), Python, Perl, Git, winflexbison, and dependencies are required; difficult if one must submit a request to install all these packages.

Comment: @kmiklas if you want to install minimum  dependencies,you can edit options in CMakeOptions.txt,set all BUILD_XXXXX option to off,then `cmake` as decribed [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWindows).Finally,cd into your plugin directory,you would see a .vcxproj file,then run `msbuild ` command.It will only compile the plugin dll and necessary dependencies.